# Saving a list in a specific format

Tags: command-line

Is there any way I can save a list in a `output.txt`, but without using the text editor to make so that:

1. before each output there should be the command used that made the list ( `list -l`, for example  or if I use two `ls` with different arguments, two separated groups of list with each of their own command used on to make them)
2. between the outputs there should be an empty line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can always create function like

```
f () { echo "$@" >> output.txt; $@ >> output.txt;  echo >> output.txt;}
```

and then write

```
f ls /
f ls /tmp
f do_something_that_produces_list
```